# Access Variable In React index.html For Branch SDK

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sdk, branch

If I add this SDK to my index.html file how would I am not able to access it in my other components. Is there another way to do this?

```
  <script>
    // load Branch
      (function(b,r,a,n,c,h,_,s,d,k){if(!b[n]||!b[n]._q){for(;s<_.length;)c(h,_[s++]);d=r.createElement(a);d.async=1;d.src="https://cdn.branch.io/branch-latest.min.js";k=r.getElementsByTagName(a)[0];k.parentNode.insertBefore(d,k);b[n]=h}})(window,document,"script","branch",function(b,r){b[r]=function(){b._q.push([r,arguments])}},{_q:[],_v:1},"addListener applyCode autoAppIndex banner closeBanner closeJourney creditHistory credits data deepview deepviewCta first getCode init link logout redeem referrals removeListener sendSMS setBranchViewData setIdentity track validateCode trackCommerceEvent logEvent disableTracking".split(" "), 0);
    // init Branch
    branch.init('key_live_kaFuWw8WvY7yn1d9yYiP8gokwqjV0Swt');
  </script>
```

Trying to access it this way in another component.

```
var options = { no_journeys: true };
branch.init('key_live_kaFuWw8WvY7yn1d9yYiP8gokwqjV0Swt', options, function(err, data) {
  console.log(err, data); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `npm` package

https://github.com/BranchMetrics/web-branch-deep-linking#quick-install

```
npm i branch-sdk
```

Then:

```
import branch from 'branch-sdk'

branch.init(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can bind the `branch` to a `window` property and access them from all over the application.

Initialize:

```
<head>
  <script>
    branch.init('key_live_kaFuWw8WvY7yn1d9yYiP8gokwqjV0Swt', options, function(err, data) {
      window.__BRANCH__ = data;
    });
  </script>
</head>
```

Usage:

```
const Component = () => (
  <button 
    onClick={() => {
      // You have access to window.__BRANCH__
    }}
  >
    Button
  </button>
);
```

Comment: If I want to store the branch data to redux, where should I handle that? Because after I bind `branch` to `window.__BRANCH__`, in my `App.jsx` `componentDidMount`, I can't access the branch data to redirect the user (depending on if they're logged in).